# How to keep track of number of launches on an app?

Tags: java, android, listener

I'm trying to make an Android app and I would like to create some kind of Listener   to watch how many times someone launches or opens the app. How would I go about this?

Comment: You can increment a counter by reading, adding 1 and resaving it in your app's main Activity `onCreate()` method. Use SharedPreferences, a text file, or whatever fits.

Answer (score 1):

I am a new developer but I can suggest something.

1.You can host a simple json page.

2.then you can whenever the onCreate ()method is called you can add a number to the json page so you can view the number of app open counts on the internet..

I hope you get the point.

Wait.. first of all tell me that you want a number on HOW Many people opened the app?
Or you want to count EACH Single person's app open count so you can do like a (daily login count per person.)

Comment: I want to count how many times a single individual opens the app, so yeah, kind of like a daily login.

Comment: So you can do is like make a global int then in the onCreate method you can increment the integer. Then you can add a conditional statement like for example : a if statement if (userdailyvisit == 2){
//do this
}

But the issue will be that if you are doing this for a daily login system then what if the user opens the app two times in a day it will mess up the integer and the app daily login system. I hope you are getting the point. So I am a new developer I don't know that much. Maybe you can add some if statements to compare the use devices time to a 24 hour day. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do it multiple ways but the most basic one is  to declare an integer for example **int counter=0;** than in onCreate in the MainActivity.java do **counter++;** and put the value in the SharedPreferences(as far as you know how to use it)
thats all